# ServiceStack.OrmLite: Reading back a TimeSpan using Untyped API results in InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, mysql, timespan, ormlite-servicestack

I let ServiceStack OrmLite (5.1.1) create the table, and persist the object, that contains a TimeSpan:

```
// ...
public TimeSpan _Jobs_VehicleNotificationTime { get; set; }
// ...
```

When I try to read it back, I get this error:

```
System.InvalidCastException: 'Invalid cast from 'System.Int64' to 'System.TimeSpan'.'
```

The value [is persisted as a `long`](https://github.com/ServiceStack/Issues/issues/15) it seems:
[image]

but I get this when using the `FromObjectDictionary` method:

[image]

Error is:

```
   at System.Convert.DefaultToType(IConvertible value, Type targetType, IFormatProvider provider)
   at ServiceStack.PlatformExtensions.ObjectDictionaryFieldDefinition.SetValue(Object instance, Object value)
   at ServiceStack.PlatformExtensions.FromObjectDictionary(IReadOnlyDictionary`2 values, Type type)
   at tWorks.Core.CoreServerCommons.Handlers.OrmLiteDbHandler.<>c__DisplayClass65_1.<ReadObjects>b__1(Dictionary`2 x) in D:\[GIT]\Core\CoreServerCommons\Handlers\DbHandlers\OrmLite\OrmLiteDbHandler.cs:line 577
```

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have resolved the issue. Maybe @mythz can tell me if this is completely wrong, but it seems to work:

**Implement your own `TimeSpanAsIntConverter`**

I first dismissed that idea, as I wrongly interpreted Mythz to the effect of Converters were not relevant or were not executed if using the Untyped API. When I did implement the TimeSpan converter, it worked just as expected:

```
namespace Commons
{
    public class MyTimeSpanConverter : TimeSpanAsIntConverter
    {
        public override string ColumnDefinition => "TIME";
        public override DbType DbType => DbType.Time;

        public override object ToDbValue(Type fieldType, object value)
        {
            TimeSpan timespan = (TimeSpan)value;
            return timespan;
        }

    }
}
```

Then, when using that converter, the table is correctly created with the `TIME` type instead of bigint, and when persisted, it all looks OK:

[image]

Test code:

```
    public void Test()
    {
        Customer c = new Customer() { Username = "TED ÅÄÖ", DeletedTime = DateTime.MaxValue, MyTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(1, 30, 0) };
        CoreObject co = c;
        long id;
        using (IDbConnection db = _dbFactory.Open())
        {
            var typedApi = db.CreateTypedApi(co.GetType());
            id = typedApi.Insert(co, selectIdentity: true);
        };

        using (IDbConnection db = _dbFactory.Open())
        {
            string tableName = co.GetType().GetModelMetadata().ModelName;
            List<Dictionary<string, object>> results = db.Select<Dictionary<string, object>>($"SELECT * FROM {tableName} where id={id}");
            List<CoreObject> coreObjects = results.Map(x => (CoreObject)x.FromObjectDictionary(co.GetType()));
        }
    }
```

Results:
[image]

This seems to resolve at least this issue for me - my TimeSpans work as expected.

Comment: This changes how `TimeSpan` are stored so the ADO.NET provider returns `TimeSpan` instead of `long` at the cost of interoperability with other RDBMS's as well as [MySql TIME Type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/time.html) not being able to store the full range of TimeSpan values.

Comment: Sure, but thats a minor issue. Now I can actually use Untyped API, which is probably the most important API in OrmLite ;-)

Answer (score 1):

TimeSpan's are stored as integer columns in OrmLite to ensure they maintain precision and behavior across all supported RDBMS's. If you're retrieving it using a dynamic resultset in an Object Dictionary then it will only be able to return the data reader value which hasn't gone through OrmLite's converters to convert it back to a `TimeSpan`, in which case you wont be able to use ServiceStack.Text's `FromObjectDictionary()` generic extension method here which does not use OrmLite's converters.

Comment: ... and since I sort of have to use the dynamic resultset, since I am loading all my "objects", not specifying at compile time what classes I should load (just the parent class `CoreObject`), the only solution is to remove the `TimeSpan`? Is there no way to enable the converters when using `FromObjectDictionary`?

Comment: ... and also - no conversian? Some convert operation needs to be done. A datetime, for example, is a stored as a string in MySql I think, which needs to be converted to a DateTime? Both DateTime and TimeSpan has constructors that takes in a `long`, why not use those? Why do we otherwise pass in a Type in the FromObjectDictionary method? Using the `new TimeSpan(54000000000)` will yield the 1h30m as expected.

Comment: And the TimeSpanConverter does just that: https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.OrmLite/Converters/TimeSpanAsIntConverter.cs. So why not do that when I use the dynamic resultset? Basically, if the Type is known at runtime, you can determine that the property is a TimeSpan, and the value is a long, then use the constructor?

Comment: @Ted that’s not how it works, when using the dynamic resultset OrmLite is being used as a raw Datamapper, it just sees the raw Type as returned by the ADO.NET provider, it doesn’t know the destination Type and so cannot use a converter.

Comment: Ok, well, thats too bad. But, I have a hard time understanding how it doesnt know the destination type, since the call looks like this: `x.FromObjectDictionary(theType)`, so `theType` is what Type it is, so it should/can know about it? Or....? =)

Comment: @Ted As mentioned in my answer FromObjectDictionary is a ServiceStack.Text generic extension method that has nothing to do with OrmLite.

Comment: Right, but if it doesnt have anything to do with OrmLite? Like a `TimeSpan`? There isnt anything specific with this object or dictionary, nothing really to do with OrmLite. But based on the object dictionary and the Type sent in, wouldnt it be possible to use the same standard factory/constructions to produce a TimeSpan, based on the Type sent in?

Comment: @Ted The logic for how TimeSpan's are serialized is in OrmLite only. The JSV/JSON Serialization supports deserializing from a double to a TimeSpan in seconds for interoperability with other JSON services but OrmLite stores .NET Ticks as a long for preserving precision. Anyway I've decided to add an Exception in AutoMapping Utils for long > TimeSpan which is available in the latest v5.1.1 on MyGet. But wont be importing other OrmLite converter behavior in SS.Text's AutoMapping Utils in future.

Comment: I failed to find the commit for this, as I wanted to look at what you changed, as I am not sure what the fix did. Do toy have an URL?

Comment: Was apart of [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/commit/f760ccaf3a531da3b2f4a20902c43e999ba3b82d), relevant lines [for TimeSpan < - > long](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/blob/be3a10642ce69c909e8ce34f499c84e5b7a00748/src/ServiceStack.Text/AutoMappingUtils.cs#L104-L107).